# How can I put the numbers of this string in a database?

Tags: string, list, parsing, vim, split

I would like to put the single line numbers of these kind of strings in a list with the name SingleLineNrs:

`\%(\%>1l.\%<4l\|\%>5l.\%<7l\|\%>9l.\%<15l\|\|\%>15l.\%<17l\|\%>17l.\%<19l\|\%>24l.\%<29l\|\%>31l.\%<33l\|\%>33l.\%<35l\)`

SingleLineNrs must be `[2,3,6,10,11,12,13,14,16,18,25,26,27,28,32,34]`

But I have no idea how to split these strings because of the `>` and `<` signs.
The problem is that I need the numbers between the `>` and `<` and not the numbers in the string self.

Comment: You are trying to extract numbers so that for the sample input string you provided in your question you end up with something like this the following? [1,5,9,15,17,24,31,33]. Is that right?

Comment: Hi Francis, The output must be as in the sample database in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can break your input string using a regex like this one:

```
>(\d+)\D+(\d+)
```

It has two capture groups:

- Group 1: The Lower bound of the integer sequence you want to create.
- Group 2: The upper bound of the integer sequence you want to create.

You would then loop through every regex match producing sequences of numbers from the bounds the match gives you.

I'm not sure what code environment you have access to. So here is a C# function that produces the output you want from the sample input string you provided.

```
private static string DecodeSequence(string encodedSequence)
{
    const string SEPARATOR = ",";
    const int GRP_LBOUND = 1, GRP_UBOUND = 2;
    Regex boundPairPattern = new Regex(@">(\d+)\D+(\d+)");
    Match matchBoundPair = boundPairPattern.Match(encodedSequence);

    var decodedSequence = new StringBuilder();
    while (matchBoundPair.Success)
    {
        int lBound = Convert.ToInt32(matchBoundPair.Groups[GRP_LBOUND].Value);
        int uBound = Convert.ToInt32(matchBoundPair.Groups[GRP_UBOUND].Value);
        for (int i = lBound + 1; i < uBound; ++i)
        {
            decodedSequence.Append(i).Append(SEPARATOR);
        }
        matchBoundPair = matchBoundPair.NextMatch();
    }
    if (decodedSequence.Length > 0) decodedSequence.Length -= SEPARATOR.Length;
    return String.Format("[{0}]", decodedSequence);
}
```

Comment: Hello Francis, thank you for replying, however I don't have a C environment. My question is a vimscript question. BTW someone has changed my tags, he removed the Vim Tag :(  - I just added it again.

Comment: @Remonn - I don't know very much about vim or its scripting language. But perhaps you could use the above code as a Filter in vim?

Answer (score -1):

When you analyze the data, you'll recognize the structure:

1. ranges delimited by `\|`
2. lower and upper bound delimited by `.`
3. a bound consists of uninteresting stuff at the front (`\%`), a sigil (`<` / `>`), a number, and uninteresting stuff at the end
4. depending on the sigil, the number needs to be increased / decreased to get the first / last line number

I would process the data step by step; each step is just a simple invocation of `split()`, `matchstr()`, `matchlist()`, or other primitive operations.

For example, the first step is

```
:echo split('\%(\%>1l.\%<4l\|\%>5l.\%<7l\|\%>9l.\%<15l\|\|\%>15l.\%<17l\|\%>17l.\%<19l\|\%>24l.\%<29l\|\%>31l.\%<33l\|\%>33l.\%<35l\)', '\\|')
```

Comment: thanks, yes for you is everything easy. I suppose you're using vim for many many years. Even with your example I can't find out how to resolve my problem p.e. there is a `\%(` at the start of the string. Don't know how to remove the `\%[<>]` and `l` in the entire string.

Comment: Your questions are about technical details of processing algorithms, so it looks like you know exactly what you want to achieve. If you are a beginner just trying to learn Vimscript, I'd suggest starting with something simpler. If OTOH you have a particular problem to solve in Vim, why don't you tell us about the problem (in user terms), instead of focusing on technical details without the surrounding context?!

Comment: Why are you always making problems of simple questions? Then you write that I have to write the vim manual. Sometimes after trying trying and reading reading and testing testing I can't find out how things works. I believe that I already asked such a question as the one above a year ago. Can't find out how!! Yes with multiple substitute commands and with a formule to add step by step a number between the `>` and `>` characters, 2 pages of code. There must be an easier way. I can't write here all this code. So if you tell me to read the help manual, please don't reply.